# Removing from list throws IndexOutOfBoundsException while iterating: Java->Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

the code worked in Java but when converted to Kotlin it is no longer works. It throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here is the original Java:

```
    grid_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selectedItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_name)).getText().toString();
            for (int j = 0;  j < itemList.size(); j++){
                String tempString = itemList.get(j);
                if(tempString.equals(selectedItem)) {
                    Log.d("Update", "Removing: " + selectedItem);
                    itemList.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the new Kotlin:

```
    grid_view!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, _, _ ->
            val selectedItem = (tag_name as TextView).text.toString()
            itemList.indices.forEach {
                val tempString = itemList[it]
                if (tempString == selectedItem) {
                    Log.d("Update", "Removing: " + selectedItem)
                    itemList.removeAt(it)
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `indices` is initialized at the first time, so the `indices` of the `forEach` operation is never changed after you remove element from a `List`, but `size()` is changed in Java, for example:

```
//                            v--- `size` is changed after remove item from List
for (int j = 0;  j < itemList.size(); j++){
  //...
}
```

For the mutable operation in Kotlin, please using  [MutableCollection#removeIf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) / [MutableCollection#removeAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html) instead, for example:

```
itemList.removeIf { it == selectedItem } // java-8

itemList.removeAll { it == selectedItem } // Kotlin
```

**AND** there is a wrong logic of your Java code, for example:

```
for (int j = 0;  j < itemList.size(); j++){
    String tempString = itemList.get(j);
    if(tempString.equals(selectedItem)) {
        itemList.remove(j--);
        //               ^
        // you should minus the current j, if don't the next is skipped
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the exception is no longer thrown. However, it still is not acting as it did before. No matter which item is clicked in grid_view the first item is removed. Log statements show that the selectedItem is always the first one.

Comment: @Roc47HS Hi, I'm not good at english. please say it clearly, sir. :)

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. The grid_view should behave where clicking on an item removes it from the list and from the grid_view. That is how it did behave in the original Java code. Now in Kotlin even if I click the second or third item in the grid_view it will remove the first item.

Comment: @Roc47HS Hi, if you want to remove one at a time, you can using `remove(position:Int)` rather than `removeAll`. then the `for` loop is no need.